# Can I use root-relative XPath expressions to get nodes in a cloned node?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Consider this code, in which we:

1) Build a simple XML document;

2) Clone one of its nodes;

3) Search with xpath for attribute `a` in node `in`:

```
@Test
public void lookupInClonedNode() throws Exception {
    String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><out a='1'><in a='2'/></out>";
    Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
    Node cloneOfOut = document.getFirstChild().cloneNode(true);
    String query = "//in/@a";
    Node attributeA = (Node) XPathFactory
            .newInstance()
            .newXPath()
            .evaluate(
                    query,
                    cloneOfOut,
                    XPathConstants.NODE
            );
    assertNotNull(attributeA);
}
```

This test fails. However, if you don't clone a node, but use the existing one, then it passes. Replace line:

```
Node cloneOfOut = document.getFirstChild().cloneNode(true);
```

with line:

```
Node cloneOfOut = document.getFirstChild();
```

to see the test pass.

I have two questions:

1. Why exactly does that happen? I would expect the test to pass in the case when a node is cloned.
2. If my method consumes a cloned node, what can I do with it to be able to perform a root-relative xpath lookup (i.e., one that starts with `/` or `//`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If I were to argument in favor of the observed behavior I would cite the XPath specification:

> A / by itself selects the root node of the document containing the context node.

But in DOM, a cloned node does not have a parent and is consequently not contained in any document.

2. You can test if the node has a parent parent or not. If it doesn't, you can create a new `Document` and import the node into it.